# Magento2 Checkout page adding buttton after phone number

Tags: magento2, checkout

We have a requirement like:

add a verify OTP Button after phone number in magento2 checkout page shipping address section.

Can anyone help me how to add This.

Thanks

Comment: Are get the solution?.Please share your solution.